# Dummy data error

Tags: errors

I'm getting this error when I imported the dummy data through WP importer.can any tell me what is the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot states the problem clearly:

```
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

Pages have a time limit inside which they need to do their work, otherwise a badly written PHP script could run forever.

This is why importing huge data sets runs into this problem. The bigger the import, the longer it takes, but your server only allows 60 seconds to do this in. You could bump up the limit but that will cause other issues and this might not be possible with your host. Some of the largest imports I've seen can take days

Instead, for anything but the smallest imports:

- Split your export into chunks, multiple files at 5MB each, use the WP CLI exporter to do this
- Import via WP CLI, there is no time limit for terminal commands

However for a hosting company, unless you can get access to WP CLI, doing what you're doing now will not work and there are no workarounds to make the browser importer screen work with medium to large imports. You may even struggle with small imports if it's shared hosting, and the results will be unreliable. What might work now may fail in a minutes time as the server gets busier and pages load slower

Comment: I'm working on Wampserver and I have uploaded it successfully for once.

Comment: Programs don't always run at the same speed, since you're on a local developer environment you should be able to run WP CLI, it's significantly more reliable. Eitherway what you tried to do took longer than the allotted time limit, hence the error, either WP CLI is the answer, or much smaller import files are the answer

Answer (score 0):

The error is "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded". 
You can increase the maximum execution time using php.ini file.

Then change `max_execution_time` = 60 line to max_execution_time = 180 or something.

[image]

Comment: This is wampserver so I can increase it but is this error will occur again when I will import it to a hosting company c-panel.Please help me I'm a beginner.

Comment: And the same error occurs again after setting the value 180

Comment: That means, to import your data takes more than 180 seconds also. In locallost you can increase value again. But follow the @tom s answer even it take(http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/245732/106350).

Comment: Now I have set the time to 1800 still error

Comment: Same error means `'Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded'` or `'Maximum execution time of 1800 seconds exceeded''`? It is important that you MUST restart the wamp server after changing the max_execution_time

Comment: Nope I have restarted wamp server still error and the error is 60seconds